# Long exact sequence in etale cohomology of a pair

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Suppose $U\subset X$ is an open subscheme in a variety $X/k$ (both assumed as nice as possible) with complement $Z$. If these were analytic spaces, then there would be an exact sequence:
$$\dots \to H^i_c(U) \to H^i_c(X) \to H^i_c(Z) \to H^{i+1}(U) \to \dots.$$
Is there a corresponding exact sequence in etale cohomology? I think one would have to be more careful with twists, what's the right statement? I think it should follow from the long exact sequence for a pair?

Comment: Yes there is also such a statement in étale cohomology. I don't remember what are the most general assumptions on $X$ and on the coefficient sheaf, but for finite type over a field and a constructible sheaf, it certainly works. No twists are needed. They only appears when we take duality. It follows from the distinguished triangle $$Rj_!j^*\to 1\to i_*i^*\overset{+1}\to $$ in $D^b_c(X)$ and application of the functor $R\Gamma_c(X,.):D^b_c(X)\to D(Ab)$ with the identifications $R\Gamma_c(X,Rj_!j^*K)=R\Gamma_c(U,j^*K)$ and $R\Gamma_c(X,i_*i^*K)=R\Gamma_c(Z,i^*K)$.

Comment: This is Theorem 7.44 (iii) in Lei Fu's book.

Comment: Thank you to both of you!